# Failed to Install SASS - MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: html, css, sass, node-sass

Today I tried to install node-sass using: `npm i -g node-sass`

but it keeps getting failed. Can anyone help?

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/huynguyen/.npm/_logs/2020-08-21T14_55_03_284Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try: `npm install -g sass` taken from [here](https://sass-lang.com/install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this on OS X, you can try

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

so that `huynguyen` will have write access.